# FIFO Capital Gains Calculation Formula

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet (Excel formulas apply) containing 2000 transactions that are structured like below:

[image]

I need to calculate the Capital Gains for every sell order and place this amount in the 5th column (as pictured). This can be achieved with either traditional formulas, or with a Google App Script.

I'm finding it difficult via formulas to match the sell order with the buy as you proceed down the table. If anyone could help with a formula or solution to tackle this problem it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't a Pivot Table in Excel do what you are expecting to?

Comment: I don't believe it will, and not if a sell parcel can be attributed and split across several buy parcels. That's the problem I'm experiencing.

Comment: Can you show by working out manually what should appear in column 5 plz?

Comment: Sure, Row 3 = 10 x ($30 - $10), where the first 10 represents the quantity sold, and the $30 - $10 is the different between the buy and sell price. This gives you the capital gain, or how much profit you made on the purchase.

Comment: I would recommend that you share a link to a sample spreadsheet wherein you manually enter the expected results for the "Capital Gains" column (with an explanation in cells off to the right where you feel it will be helpful). Up to now, you are explaining (i.e., telling) people here what you want. It is always more efficient and effective to SHOW than to TELL.

Comment: @ErikTyler that is a great idea. I opened a new question with some further clarifications to the problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67930020/profit-capital-gains-calculation-formula

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** : This screenshot is based on the OP's comment new attachment explanation

1] **Cost of Goods Sold**, `E2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((-SUMIF(B$2:B2,"<0")>SUMIF(OFFSET(B$1,,,ROW(B$1:B1)),">0"))*(-SUMIF(B$2:B2,"<0")-SUMIF(OFFSET(B$1,,,ROW(B$1:B1)),">0"))*(C$2:C2-N(+C$1:C1)))-SUM(E$1:E1)
```

2] **Capital Gains**, `F2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(B2>0,0,-B2*C2-E2)
```

3] **Total Capital Gains**, `F6` enter formula :

```
=SUM(F2:F5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It seems that it partially worked for the bottom too. I just tried, and E4 should be a $200 profit but it's showing as $0. Formula is $200 = 10 units sold x ($30 - $10), where the first 10 represents the quantity sold, and the $30 - $10 is the different between the buy and sell price. 

I also tried with partial sales, it didn't seem to account for that either as seen in this screenshot - https://i.imgur.com/fAGQ3bj.png

Comment: @CompiledSanity, please see my new edited post and formula.

Comment: I might be missing it, but where does Company (col A) fit into this?

Comment: That will be a new question, one post one question. Open a new post for it.

Comment: From the OP's comment above *"Row 3 = 10 x ($30 - $10), where the first 10 represents the quantity sold, and the $30 - $10 is the different between the buy and sell price"*, it is part of this question. The capital gain on the sale of Company A is related to only Company A shares.

Comment: Apologies all you're absolutely right, I over simplified it in that screenshot but the original screenshot is still the end goal. I've created a new question with a fully fleshed out scenario and example doc here if you wanted to take a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67930020/profit-capital-gains-calculation-formula

Comment: @bosco_yip Great solution and thanks for the revision. I'm still having some difficulty getting this to work if there are buy orders mixed inbetween sell orders. I've uploaded a sample doc here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67930020/profit-capital-gains-calculation-formula