# Calculate Profit/Capital Gains on Sold Inventory/Shares

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet (Excel formulas apply) containing 2000 transactions that are structured like below:

[image]

[Link to Google Sheet with example calcs here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VfjTFH7LtVI2jb1PxWEx2Kozv7jCft6FsBaY5DfCr0A/edit?usp=sharing)

I need to calculate the Profit (ie. FIFO Capital Gains) for every sell order and place this amount in the 5th column (as pictured). This can be achieved with either traditional formulas or with a Google App Script. Preferably in Google Sheets.

I'm finding it difficult via formulas to match the sell order with the buy as you proceed down the table as some sell orders are split across multiple buy lines. If anyone could help with a formula or solution to tackle this problem it would be much appreciated. [This is an updated question to the original here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899452/fifo-capital-gains-calculation-formula/67901443)

Comment: Side note: Excel formulas do *not* necessarily apply to Sheets, and vice versa.

Comment: @BigBen Absolutely, but for similar problems I've found SUMIFS and MAX(),MIN() are still transferable. I am also agnostic to platform, so either an Excel or Google Sheet solution will work great.

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately there's many questions asked on this site where Excel/Sheets tags are used together where they shouldn't be (e.g. the solution involves the QUERY function in Sheets), which is why sticking to the relevant tags is better ... but rolled back to include the Excel tags.

Comment: @BigBen many thanks, appreciate it :)

Comment: Some explanation here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8Ik2FVY3No

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Thank you for this. It looks like the data needs to be adapted into that particular data layout (purchases and sales separated) which will be difficult to do on the fly in this case.

Comment: Was your original question ever answered?

Comment: @markfitzpatrick no answer! Closest I came was this Sheet, the only thing missing is a config setting for a capital gains discount after the first year of 50% - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PBRyOlLQLH7bzP55XB2hQfAFQSA3YbyTv9kKy6XOlWU/edit?usp=sharing

If you know how to do this with the last column (V) in the Tax tab, let me know!

Comment: I got it.  Will share soln when I get back from the shop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PRELIMINARY CONTEXT

Screenshot below refers:

[image: Functions to derive Profit Vector]

Google sheets [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ya_KfSXVDb8ARR98vqa-eg8jCAv2WdoRHUKJpNQQ3Y4/edit?usp=sharing)

IMPORTANT UPDATE: re: 2000+ rows, see link in my last comment (for OneDrive template, s.t. expiry, and bottom of this proposal for screenshot of error "too large to import")

fyi: *(Office 365 - Excel - fns. such as 'filter' etc., so #Name! will be ubiquitous upon opening this link; however, sharing this should serve as a convenient means to replicate above screenshot in the correct version of Excel)*

---

### REQUIREMENTS

1. Office 365
2. Adequate space to the right or ability to utilise extra sheet for calcs as req.

---

### APPROACH

**High-level | Take-aways**

• Relies on 2 additional tables: Qty 'depletion' table (here - G:P) and corresp. Profit Vectors (here - R:Z)

• Compressed representations (2x2 tables, per Summary Tables, here: rows 19:32) could be explored to simplify matters (albeit these are still Work in Progress ['WiP'])

• VB could be attractive alternative too

**Low-level | Procedural**

1. Single-cell function could not be found without exceptional complication (however, suspect it could be possible e.g. using FilterXML?)
2. Qty label transposes filtered negative quantities (grey shaded, G3: J3)
3. These values are depleted in turn (from left to right, i.e. dependency on having data sorted in ascending order by date (in this depiction, data first sorted by 'fruit' as these are assumed to be independent in the context of the profit calc.)
4. For example, -5 quantity (G3) offset by +10 (B3) to yield +5 which, in turn contributes towards the -35 qty (H3) to yield -30.  No further contribution can be made (left to right); next row (5): +20 avail (given), no offset against -5 (G3, already 'reimbursed', so 20 offset against -30 (H4) to yield -10, and so forth.
5. Worksheet set up to accommodate longer list of fruit / profits
6. Result table of residual 'quantities' (~ G:J) applied to price differential to yield 'profit vectors' (R:U) which are summed against corresponding negative quantities to produce Profit score (yellow shaded cells)

---

### FUNCTIONS

Salient functions (all of which should be available within Google Sheet, but for completeness):

**1) Profit calc. (E4, drag down):**

```
=IF(B4<0,SUM(INDEX($R$4:$AA$13,0,MATCH(A4&C4,$R$2:$AA$2&$R$3:$AA$3,0))),"")
```

This can be dragged down / to right as far as desired (in this case, goes to: Z13)

**2) Qty table - contents (G4)**

```
=IF($A4=G$2,IF(G$3<>"",IF(G$2=E$1,IF($B4<0,IF(G3<0,G3,0), IF(E4<0,0,E4)+IF(G3<0,G3,0)), IF(G$3<>"", IF($B4<0,IF(G3<0,G3,0),$B4 + IF(G3<0,G3,0))))),G3)
```

**3) Qty table - headers (G2, G3 resp.)**

```
=MID(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A4:A13&B4:B13,B4:B13<0)),1,SEARCH("-",TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A4:A13&B4:B13,B4:B13<0)))-1)

=-1*MID(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A4:A13&B4:B13,B4:B13<0)),SEARCH("-",TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A4:A13&B4:B13,B4:B13<0)))+1,LEN(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A4:A13&B4:B13,B4:B13<0))))
```

Drag to right as far as desired / able to (this case have been dragged to col. P)

**4) Profit table - contents (R4, drag down/right)**

```
=IF(R$2<>"",IF(G3>0,0,IF(G4>0,ABS(G3),G4-G3))*(R$3-$C4),"")
```

**5) Profit table - headers (R2, R3 resp.):**

```
=MID(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A4:A13&"-"&$C$4:$C$13,B4:B13<0)),1,SEARCH("-",TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A4:A13&"-"&$C$4:$C$13,B4:B13<0)))-1)

=1*MID(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A4:A13&"-"&$C$4:$C$13,B4:B13<0)),SEARCH("-",TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A4:A13&"-"&$C$4:$C$13,B4:B13<0)))+1,LEN(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A4:A13&"-"&$C$4:$C$13,B4:B13<0))))
```

### MISC

- Alternate solutions derived & explored include triangular frameworks
  (rows 17-32).
- These tabulate the interaction between values assoc.
  with positive and negative quantities positive/negative quantities
  (and corres. dates)
- Should be noted these are otherwise unnecessary (in terms of functions, previous 'section'

Continuing in the same vein as before....

**6a) 1st summary table (Qty): row and col headers (A22 - drag down, C19 - drag right resp.):**

```
=FILTER(D4:D13,1*IF($A$21="*",1,(A4:A13=$A$21))*(B4:B13<0))

=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(D4:D13,1*IF($A$21="*",1,IFERROR((A4:A13=$A$21),1))*(B4:B13>0)))
```

**6b) 1st summary table (Qty): running total (c19, drag down / right as req., in this case: to P19)**

```
=SUM($C21:C21,$B22#)
```

**6c) 1st summary table (Qty): content (c22, drag down or tonight as req.)**

```
=IF(OR(C$20="",$A22=""),"",IF($A22>C$20,MAX(0,C21+MIN(0,SUM($B22:B22))),C21))
```

**7) 2nd summary table (Profits): C29, not draggable**

```
=MIN(C$21,C$21+$B22)*($B29-C$28)
```

Note; other features of 2nd summary table (row / col headers) follow from 1st.  Also, placing '*' in the fruit selection cell (A21) returns all (this is still WiP as mentioned previously).

---

### SCREENSHOTS FOR LARGER UPLOAD:

[image: Screenshot: "too large to upload" error]

[image: MAIN TAB - link in comments]

[image: PRO TAB - link in comments]

[image: QTY TAB - link in comments]

Comment: This is absolutely INCREDIBLE. You are truly gifted at Excel, I'll need some time to work through this and understand. Thank you for such an incredible writeup to help break it all apart and provide alternatives. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to make this compatible with Google Sheets? 

I use an automation to automatically dump data in this sheet so it would be advantageous to keep it online. This is still fantastic as an offline sheet however and I'm super grateful! Will work through now and mark as an answer once validated.

Comment: If possible for another feature request, as is common in a lot of countries (I can see this becoming a great Excel for the community to use) there is a tax discount applied to profits made when you hold an asset longer than 1 year. Could you apply an example 30% tax rate for those held under a year and a 15% tax rate for those over a year? And could you adapt so that the transaction area can stretch to infinity? I'm trying to dump all my 2000 rows of data in to validate but I can't move the summary tables without breaking everything. You're a wizard, thank you so much for having a go at this!

Comment: Glad it helped.  You should be able to confirm / agree the basic request has been addressed and accept this so long (given the dearth responses / proposals to your Q, I have my doubts a better one will surface anytime soon :) - i.e. you can see this reconciles to the sample data you provided.  StackOverflow is not a freelancer.com website/community, so 'feature' requests would be stretching it a little.  Having said that, I've 'gone the extra mile' and produced a template that allows 5000 rows (with real fruit, go wiki) - expires tom: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j960sBcvGBPP6tNbZq?e=SSp3G0

Comment: pw = my name backwards, lowercase.

Comment: Apologies, you're absolutely right. I didn't meant to come across as seeking free freelancing work, this is just a genuinely tricky problem and it's difficult when retracing someone elses work. Genuinely appreciate your extension to 5000 rows, this will be a great help and I'll see what I can do to adapt :)

Answer provided and well and truly deserved. You're a wizard James, thank you!

Comment: No prob. mate, likewise didn't mean to come across with any accusations ! :) glad we see eye to eye.  Did you give my link in pvs comment a go (if so, all good/working for you?) will try sort you out a different way (e.g. 1k rows might work) but will get to other problems/solutions for other users otherwise.  Check my  home page if you're interested in larger-scale projects etc.  Best wishes with/for this one! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233713/discussion-between-james-and-compiledsanity).